# How to upload conDB.php to Hostinger?

Tags: android, upload, database-connection, hosting

I really don't know how to upload conDB.php file to hostinger.
I wonder if I upload that file to File Manager 2 (that the only one I have, not File Manager and File Manager 3), will this be ok? 
Could I post data what I want to send to server? 
Answer me please...

Answer (score 1):

you can upload your PHP files in filemanger2

find the below image.First click on filemanger2.then Click Public Html.as show in image.[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bef2B.png)

Then upload your DBconn file in that.as show in image.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/288Yi.png)

thanks :)

Comment: thank q :) I already upload under other folder. I'm working on it.